# How can I retain data in existing list items when adding a new list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am aware of the many related solutions to this problem but mine differs because I'm able to add a new item to existing list items, what I noticed, however, is that the entire list is recreated, to include the newly added list. The implication of this is that the data entered in the existing items are refreshed because of creating new list items. How can I resolve this issue, please? I need to retain the data in the existing list.

So far, everything is working well as a new row is created, but it refreshes the whole list, thereby losing information already entered in the existing lists

HTML

```
<ul id="debit_entries_container">
                                <div class="line-heading">
                                    <label class="but"></label>
                                    <label class="type">Type</label>
                                    <label class="cat">Category</label>
                                    <label class="name">Name</label>
                                    <label class="code">Code</label>
                                    <label class="bal">Balance</label>
                                    <label class="amount">Debit Amount</label>
                                </div>
                                <li data-debit-entry-list>
                                    <div class="but" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                                        <button type="button" data-add-debit-line onclick="newDebitRow();">+</button>
                                        <button type="button" data-remove-debit-line>-</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <select name="debit_account_type" class="type" title="select account type" data-debit-account-type>
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="asset">Asset</option>
                                        <option value="expense">Expense</option>
                                        <option value="liability">Liability</option>
                                        <option value="fund">Fund</option>
                                        <option value="revenue">Revenue</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <select name="debit_account_category" class="cat" title="select account category" data-debit-account-category>
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <select name="debit_account_name" class="name" title="select one of the names" data-debit-account-name>
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" name="debit_account_number" required class="code" data-debit-account-number readonly/>
                                    <p class="bal">0.00</p>
                                    <input type="text" name="debit_account_amount"
                                           placeholder="&#8358; 0.00" onkeyup="debitAmountEntry();" required
                                           class="amount" data-debit-account-amount/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

JavaScript

```
    function newDebitRow() {
     let debitEntriesContainer = document.getElementById('debit_entries_container');
     let newRow = `
     <li data-debit-entry-list>
          <div class="but" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
          <button type="button" data-add-debit-line onclick="newDebitRow();">+</button>
          <button type="button" data-remove-debit-line>-</button>
          </div>
          <select name="debit_account_type" class="type" title="select account type" data-debit-account-type>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="asset">Asset</option>
          <option value="expense">Expense</option>
          <option value="liability">Liability</option>
          <option value="fund">Fund</option>
          <option value="revenue">Revenue</option>
          </select>
          <select name="debit_account_category" class="cat" title="select account category" data-debit-account-category>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
          <select name="debit_account_name" class="name" title="select one of the names" data-debit-account-name>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="debit_account_number" required class="code" data-debit-account-number readonly/>
          <p class="bal">0.00</p>
          <input type="text" name="debit_account_amount"
               placeholder="&#8358; 0.00" onkeyup="debitAmountEntry();" required
               class="amount" data-debit-account-amount/>
     </li>
     `
     debitEntriesContainer.innerHTML += newRow;
     getAllButtons();
     debitEntriesChanges();
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives error. Please change the snippet into a [mcve] - it seems you posted credit code and debit add

Comment: If the newDebitRow  code is the same, then there is no reason for the content to disappear.

Comment: Okay...I'd rewrite the code. But in simple terms, adding a new list item to existing ones with +=, recreates the new list items instead of just adding the new list item to the existing ones. The information in the existing items is lost, that is what I needed to avoid.

Comment: You mean the container is reflowed and the form elements are reset

Comment: Exactly. Refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use innerHTML. Instead appendChild with a cloned LI will work better

I would also delegate

NOTE: I changed the add and remove to just have class="add" and class="remove" - now no need to know if it is debit or credit

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".add")) {
    const container = tgt.closest("ul");
    const newRow = container.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)
    newRow.querySelectorAll("select").forEach(sel => sel.value = "");
    newRow.querySelectorAll("[type=text]").forEach(txt => txt.value = "");
    container.appendChild(newRow);
  } else if (tgt.matches(".remove")) {
    tgt.closest("li").remove()
  }
})
document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("[name=credit_account_amount]")) {
    creditAmountEntry()
  } else if (tgt.matches("[name=debit_account_amount]")) {
    debitAmountEntry()
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="debit_entries_container">

  <li data-debit-entry-list>
    <div class="but" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
    </div>
    <select name="debit_account_type" class="type" title="select account type" data-debit-account-type>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="asset">Asset</option>
      <option value="expense">Expense</option>
      <option value="liability">Liability</option>
      <option value="fund">Fund</option>
      <option value="revenue">Revenue</option>
    </select>
    <select name="debit_account_category" class="cat" title="select account category" data-debit-account-category>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <select name="debit_account_name" class="name" title="select one of the names" data-debit-account-name>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="debit_account_number" required class="code" data-debit-account-number readonly/>
    <p class="bal">0.00</p>
    <input type="text" name="debit_account_amount" placeholder="&#8358; 0.00" required class="amount" data-debit-account-amount/>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="credit_entries_container">

  <li data-credit-entry-list>
    <div class="but" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
    </div>
    <select name="credit_account_type" class="type" title="select account type" data-credit-account-type>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="asset">Asset</option>
      <option value="expense">Expense</option>
      <option value="liability">Liability</option>
      <option value="fund">Fund</option>
      <option value="revenue">Revenue</option>
    </select>
    <select name="credit_account_category" class="cat" title="select account category" data-credit-account-category>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <select name="credit_account_name" class="name" title="select one of the names" data-credit-account-name>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="credit_account_number" required class="code" data-credit-account-number readonly/>
    <p class="bal">0.00</p>
    <input type="text" name="credit_account_amount" placeholder="&#8358; 0.00" required class="amount" data-credit-account-amount/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd study how to go with this, I'm not at this level of JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, I really had to clean the code. Assuming the debit and credit ULs are the same structure, I have simplified the handling A LOT

Comment: Quick one please, I have actually utilized the code, but the `firstElementChild` in my ul is a div which is the heading. Is it possible to change it to the 'secondElementChild'? which is the li

Comment: And yes, same structure, just name difference, debit and credit.